# salvar div para pdf preservando css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Olá, estou tentando salvar pdf usando o script jspdf, mas não está funcionando corretamente, o código é:

```
var pdf;
pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
pdf.addHTML(window.parent.tela_frame.document.getElementById("resize-container"), function() {
    pdf.save('stacking-plan.pdf');
});
```

No meu pdf pode ter formas como circulos, retangulos, etc..
O circulo não está ficando circular, ele ta virando um retangulo ao salvar...
Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

EDIT:
codigo html gerado pelo site dentro do iframe, todas as divs tem o mesmo estilo de montagem, tipo elas sao geradas dinamicamente dentro do article resize-container.

```
<article class="resize-container" id="resize-container" onclick="normalizaEdit()"><div id="obj0" contenteditable="false" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  left:0px; top:0px" onclick="move_posicao(this)" ondblclick="" class="resize-drag objeto_tela" tipo="retangulo">a</div><div id="obj1" contenteditable="true" style="background: rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.5); color: black;" onclick="move_posicao(this)" ondblclick="editar(this)" class="resize-drag objeto_tela" tipo="retangulo">a</div><div id="obj2" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: yellow; color: black;" onclick="move_posicao(this)" ondblclick="editar(this)" class="resize-drag objeto_tela" tipo="retangulo">a</div><div id="obj3" contenteditable="false" style="background-image: url('img/teste.png'); background-size:100% 100%; width:200px; height:200px; border-radius: 50%;" onclick="move_posicao(this)" ondblclick="" class="resize-drag resize-container circulo objeto_tela" tipo="circulo"></div><div id="obj4" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: pink; color: black;" onclick="move_posicao(this)" ondblclick="editar(this)" class="resize-drag objeto_tela" tipo="retangulo">a</div><div id="obj5" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: red; color: black; border:1px solid black; width:500px; height:500px; border-radius: 80%;" onclick="move_posicao(this)" ondblclick="" class="resize-drag circulo objeto_tela" tipo="circulo"></div></article>
```

Comment: Pronto, coloquei ele

Comment: Se  tiver alguma duvida quanto ao css na classe circle uso apenas border-radius: 50%;